# Files edited with nano are corrupted after reboot or shutdown

Tags: ssh, sd-card, jessie-lite, file

I came across this problem with my RPi 2 model B many times this last month, and I wanted to ask your opinion about it. The problem occurred with Raspbian Jessie Lite, both the 23/09/2016 version and the previous one. I connect to the RPi via `ssh` from my laptop. The RPi is adequately powered.

Basically, when I edit a file with `nano` and I reboot or shutdown/start the RPi, I often find out that the file has been corrupted. This happened with configuration files for `transmission/daemon` or `samba`, but also with `crontab`. With corrupted I mean that usually half or more of the file has been overwritten by random sequences of `^@` and last time I even noticed that half of the `crontab` had been copy-pasted to the file `/etc/transmission/daemon/settings.json` which I previously edited. Another time the RPi failed to boot altogether.

My question is: is this a known bug/problem with either `nano` or Raspbian? Or maybe it is a failing micro SD? Or, worse, could it be the RPi itself?

<sub>Currently I don't have a different micro SD to try out, I will edit the question as soon as I get one.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities (given that if there was a bug in nano or Raspbian there would be several thousand reports).

1. You are not saving the file (unlikely).
2. Your SD card has a corrupt filesystem.

To eliminate 1 all you need to do is use the `sync` command from the command line after saving the file (to ensure it is written to the SD card) and cat the file.

Comment: So this means that ctrl+X in nano isn't enough to save the file? Alright, I will try the `sync` command, thank you very much!

Comment: Linux will do an auto sync every now and then (certainly before a shutdown) so I doubt the lack of sync is the problem.  But it's worthwhile to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I tried with a different micro SD and so far so good, I didn't experience any of the problems described in my question. Also, the `sync` command didn't work. I'm accepting your answer given that point 2. is the likely explanation.

Comment: @NicolaBastianello Have you seem Milliways answer below.  Perhaps you weren't actually saving the file.

Comment: No, I'm sure I was saving it, I always typed 'y' when prompted to save or discard the changes and the confirmed the name of the file I wanted to save.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> in nano doesn't save the file, just exit the editor. You need to Writeout with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: It'll ask if you want to save though